What's the meaning of these jet fighter pilots gestures?
As per title, what's the meaning of the following gestures (if any)?







I expect #3 (both hands up) is to show the ground crew that he is NOT touching the stick or throttle. As the ground crew makes their final prelaunch inspection, Snuffy does not want to get bashed in the head by a moving horizontal stab, or sucked into the engine if he spins it up at the wrong moment.

Please provide the original source for each photo.

ORIGINAL SOURCES:EDITS FROM TIKTOK!!

It looks like some of them are just posing for the photo.
